# Microphone is set to max each time i plug a headset

Tags: microphone

Each time i plug my headphones, my mic just resets and increases its sensibility to the maximum and just destroys the ears of my friends and i have to go in pulseaudio to decrease the sensibility.

My mic is integrated in my laptop.

Any idea on how to prevent that ?

Thanks

Comment: What is your OS/Version?

Comment: Suggestion: You can graphically view all options with pavucontrol. Is there another microphone on your headphones ? I'm not sure how headphones can reset a microphone.

Comment: My version is ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: There is! i changed the profile of my headphones in the pulse audio to ignore its microphone, but the issue is still there !